# Generating a Certificate for Local HTTP/2 Proxy

Tags: firefox, proxy, ssl-certificate, http2, nghttp2

I'm trying to get Firefox nightly to use a secure HTTP/2 proxy, but it's refusing to accept a self-signed certificate.

The proxy is composed of nghttp2 as the HTTP/2 front-end and a simple Twisted proxy as the back-end. The Twisted code is from https://wiki.python.org/moin/Twisted-Examples and works on its own as a HTTP/1.1 proxy. nghttp2 is invoked with

```
nghttpx -s -flocalhost,8443 -b127.0.0.1,8080 server.pem server.pem -L INFO
```

Firefox is using it as a proxy as specified in https://nghttp2.org/documentation/nghttpx-howto.html#http-2-proxy-mode.

I created server.pem for localhost using

```
openssl req -new -x509 -keyout server.pem -out server.pem -days 365 -nodes
```

When I try to load a generic website like http://www.something.com through the proxy, Firefox brings up the "This Connection is Untrusted" warning. However, if I tell it to add and store the exception, it just brings up the warning again. From what I can tell, it's never making it past the nghttp2 front-end to the Twisted proxy.

Am I supposed to be doing something different for secure proxy certificated? I can't find much online other than nghttp2 stating, "Please note that both Firefox nightly and Chromium require valid certificate for secure proxy."

Comment: It seems to be working with Chrome, so I'm assuming this is an issue with Firefox.

Comment: It looks like I spoke too soon about Chrome. Chrome currently incorrectly implements HTTP/2 CONNECT: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=433784

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patrick McManus answered almost exactly this in the [Firefox bugzilla a while ago](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=378637#c65) - and the reason for this is that there is still a lack of UI for this in Firefox:

> You can do a TOFU exception for the proxy case, but you have to do it
>   a little differently.
>
> 1. turn off the proxy use in firefox.
> 2. put https://PROXYNAME:PROXYPORT/ in the location bar (use the same name and port number as you have configured in the PAC - you can't use
>      ip addresses or default ports.. you can't use ip addresses because
>      they can't be verified by the PKI and exceptions are stored per port.
> 3. override the cert warning and perm. store the exception. The response you get will be meaningless as you are now addressing the
>      proxy port as if it was an endpoint
> 4. turn the proxy back on and use it.